# Excel recursive function to create a concatenated string

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im a newbie with excel but was wondering if the following is possible with an excel formula

**Data:**

```
ID  ServiceEntryID  PartID  Comment  ServiceTypeIDs  PartDescription
1        2           54      xyz      1               hellothere
2        2           22                               howdy
3        33          54      uhu      1               xyz
```

**Desired String format**

PartID~PartDescription~ServiceTypeIDs~Comment

**Desired String value**

so for service entry ID column with value 2:

54 ~ hellothere ~ 1 ~ xyz | 22 ~ howdy ~ null ~ |

for service entry ID column with value 33:

33 ~ xyz ~ 1 ~ uhu

Comment: the pike delimeter is for multiple service entries. if the comment is missing i do not add anything whereas if the servicetypeids is missing then its a null. i know its a little weird

Comment: Not sure if a simple formula will accomplish this; maybe an Excel expert knows. Of course, should be very much possible using a macro.

Comment: @tamtam do you need concatenate values EXACTLY as typed: `33 ~ xyz ~ 1 ~ uhu` - or I'm missing something?

Comment: @tamtam If comment is missing - you want `null` instead, is it ok? and what about missing `ServiceTypeIDs`?

Comment: @tam, how many the multiple service entries are possible for a single service entry ID (and thus would be concatenated together with the "pike".

Comment: Is there anything you've tried or researched? SU is to help when you've tried on your own and run into a problem. Knowing what you've already tried is valuable to those attempting to help you.

Comment: @Peter If comment is missing then there will be no null however if service type id is missing then it is null

Comment: for multiple service entries they will be concatented with the pike sign

Comment: @tamtam I don't think pure formula solution is possible - since you need to concatenate strings from many rows: `CONCATENATE` function does not work in ARRAY mode. There are many related threads for similar case on SO - it's either UDF or VBA (which is actually the same in the context given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible (but I regret not the best place to start learning Excel!)

1. Work on a copy.
2. Sort in ServiceID order.
3. Add a column (say `G`, say labelled ‘String’) that concatenates as required for each row independently.
4. Select array and Subtotal:
5. At each change in ServiceEntryID, Use function Count. Add subtotal to: String.
6. Enter in `H2` `=IF(ISNUMBER(G2),"",H1&G2)` and copy down as far as required.
7. Select entire sheet, Copy, Paste Special, Values.
8. Subtotal Remove all.
9. Insert (shift down) `H1`.
10. Filter on ServiceEntryID, Does Not Contain: `c`, delete selected rows.
11. In column with ServiceEntryID replace ‘ Count’ with nothing.
12. Delete “Grand” and columns with labels only.